# queryIntentActivities returns different results with same code

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am implementing a popupbridge as described here: https://github.com/braintree/popup-bridge-android

The example project works fine but I am having problems getting the bridge to work in my app. I have followed the instructions and added the following necessary code to my  `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.popupbridge.PopupBridgeActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.popupbridge" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The thing is that **it works on one emulator but not on any other devices**. I have tried clearing the caches and restarting Android Studio, and wiping the data of the emulators that it's not working on.

After some debugging I found that the `popup-bridge-android` library depends on the `browser-switch-android` library: https://github.com/braintree/browser-switch-android

The part of the code where it goes wrong is below. On the emulator where the bridge is working `mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)` finds 1 activity, but on the other devices it finds 0. I don't see why it's not finding any activities. It should match the activity that I set in the manifest and find that one.

```
private boolean isReturnUrlSetup() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .setData(Uri.parse(getReturnUrlScheme() + "://"))
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);

        return availableActivities(intent).size() == 1;
    }

    private List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities(Intent intent) {
        return mContext.getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    }
```

To summarize: **The problem is that `queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)` is returning different results for the same code.**

What could be causing that? Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this was happening but the underlying problem has been solved now so I don't have this issue anymore. The reason it was working on one device was probably because it had worked earlier and something was cached.